# How many gyms can a single player take over in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

The more gyms we put our Pokemons in the more coin & stardust we gain per day. So my question is, is there a limit to the amount of gym a trainer can put his/her pokemon? If so what is the limit?

Comment: The limit is the amount of Pokémon you have. :P

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no limit to how many gyms you can control.

However you can only get a maximum defender bonus of 10. So after controlling more than 10 gyms you will no longer get additional coins and stardust each day.

Comment: Also, good luck trying to keep a lot of pokemon at gyms. they tend to get attacked pretty quickly, especially if it is a popular area

Comment: @Dragonrage yeh I tend to just go around at like 2am, collect 10 gyms then collect my defender bonus

Comment: must be nice to have that many gyms nearby. i live in the middle of nowhere when it comes to gyms and pokestops

Comment: @Dragonrage They arne't that nearby, I drive mostly for them.

Answer (score 0):

With the updated gym mechanics implemented in June 2017, you are now limited to 20 simultaneous gyms.  And, coin earnings are also topped out at 50/day, but that is independent of the number of gyms you take over.

[source 1](http://comicbook.com/gaming/2017/06/22/pokemon-go-maximum-pokemon-in-gym-per-player/)

[source 2](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/6iw2on/limit_on_how_many_pok%C3%A9mon_can_be_placed_in_gyms/)